# Custom UITableview Cell On The Basis Of Data Item

Tags: ios, uitableview

### All thing is fine but , i need while array object text is Equal `@"Add Station"` i want to create an `UILabel` in there table view cell, but I'm not able to do that can any one help me :

In .h`:

```
arrPlaceholder = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Station Name",@"source Station",@"destination Station",@"Add Station", nil];
```

in `.m`:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return [arrPlaceholder count];
}


-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentyfire = @"cellIdentyfire";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentyfire];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentyfire];
       UITableView *tblView = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:kTagTblStn];
            UITextField *txtDetails = [[UITextField alloc]init];
            txtDetails.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0,tblView.frame.size.width-10, 44);
            [txtDetails.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
            txtDetails.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            txtDetails.delegate = self;
            txtDetails.tag = kTagTxtStn;
            txtDetails.delegate = self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:txtDetails];
    }
    UITextField *fillTblTxt = (UITextField *)[fillRowCell.contentView viewWithTag:kTagTxtStn];
    fillTblTxt.placeholder = [arrPlaceholder objectAtIndex:indexDetails.row];    
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    #Your Code
    if([[textContainingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] equalToString:@"Add StationName"]){
      #Add Label here
      #Then Add Label to cell
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to this purpose.
1:use two kind of cell ,one with UILabel and the other use not, you also need two Identifiers for reuse, in cellForRowAtIndexPath function, get cell by indentifier.

2:this is a simple trick, just create UILabel for all the cell, and set the label hide property according by the array content. it need less code but more views